Conditional formatting based off multiple criteria
I'm trying to highlight a cell in column K if it meets all of the following criteria:
-if the cell above it is a date that is older than a year
-if the cell in column K is blank
-if the cell in column F on the same row as the blank cell is older than a year
Is it possible to do this? I've tried multiple different formatting rules and can't get it to work properly. Here is a section of the spreadsheet in question:
Spreadsheet Screenshot

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Show your work, so far.

The furthest along that I have gotten is with the following custom formula and it only gets me to the point of highlighting all blank cells within column K that has a date in column F older than a year. I can't figure out how to add the last requirement which is to only highlight cells that also have a date above them older than a year. Here is what I have so far: =AND($F1<(TODAY()-365), ISBLANK($K1))

Please try the conditional formatting formula: =AND(OFFSET($K1,-1,0)<>"",OFFSET($K1,-1,0)+365<TODAY(),$K1="",IF($K1="",$F1,0))


Format the column K from the cell K2 using a formula:
=AND(F2<TODAY()-365,K2="",K1<TODAY()-365,K1<>"")

